# MPLAB X IDE v 5.40 New project : Unable to set target controller

Tags: embedded, mplab

I downloaded MPLAB X IDE v5.40, while trying to create a standalone-project, i am unable to see the target spec window.

I want to set the target as "PIC16f887".
The next window after i click on Standalone-project is as the below image:
[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: To me it looks as if you need to type a name for the project file.

Comment: I tried adding the project name, <default_name> to "EmbeddedExample" but still it doesnt allow me to proceed to "next" page of setup

Comment: Did you try another file path?

Comment: Yeah i tried that as well, i want to use the older versions, as i was able to comfortably work with those

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already work it out, but the same thing happened to me, I contacted Microchip for help, and we sort it out with the following procedure:

1.Close and reopen MPLAB X

2.Try removing the User and cache directories and then re-start the IDE without importing the previous settings

User directory: C:\Users\I14533\AppData\Roaming\mplab_ide\dev\v5.40

Cache directory: C:\Users\I14533\AppData\Local\mplab_ide\Cache\dev\v5.40\var

3. Uninstall MPLAB X with ALL directories.
4. Disable Antivirus and Firewalls
5. Disable the Proxy setting under Tools->Options ->General> disable proxy
6. Install MPLAB again.
7. Try creating a sample project and compile your code.

It really worked. It no longer ask for target location. After that I set up Antivirus, Firewall and Proxy again and everything still worked well.